# Sort by date - Swift 3

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a func getData() which retrieves core data entity, and I want to sort them by date. How can I apply NSPredicate or Predicate to get the data from CoreData sorted by date?

My core data entity:
Entity: Expenses
Attributes:

- amount
- category
- date

  func getData() {
  let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

  ```
    do {
        expenses = try context.fetch(Expenses.fetchRequest())
    } catch {
        print("Cannot fetch Expenses")
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: Lookup `NSSortDescriptor` ...

Comment: predicate will not be necessary if you want all data in sorted form. Something like `sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "date" ascending: true)]` should work.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Predicates are for filtering your search results. To *sort* them you need to use an NSSortDescriptor. Assuming you have an attribute on your Expenses entity called date of type Date:

```
func getData() {
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext  

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Expenses>(entityName: "Expenses")
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Expenses.date), ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    do {
       expenses = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch {
        print("Cannot fetch Expenses")
    }
}
```

EDIT: I should have mentioned that the sort selector is added in an array so that multiple sort descriptors can be added if needed. e.g. sort first by date, then by number of legs, then by volume, etc.

Comment: This solved everything, thank you very much. But this line is in incorrect

`let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Expenses> = Expenses.fetchRequest()`

It should be

`let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Expenses>(entityName: "Expenses")`

Answer (score 18):

You need a sort descriptor to get all the objects in a specific order.

```
let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
```

Answer (score 3):

My function to do a fetchRequest of data in Core Data and sort the results by date "timestamp" in descending order. "Ruta" is the name of the entity.

```
//Array of Ruta entity
    rutas = [Ruta]()

    func getData() {

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Ruta")
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: false)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

        do {
            rutas = try context.fetch(request) as! [Ruta]
        } catch {
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**In swift 4 or swift 5, you can use like**

```
 func sortlist(){

    //1
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "User")
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    //3
    do {
        let  langugeCodes = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for result in langugeCodes as [NSManagedObject] {
            var   username:String = result.value(forKey: "username")! as! String

            print("username==>",username)


        }


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data which are lastly added at first, need to set key of sort descriptor as ObjectId.

```
let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Entity.ObjectId)
ascending: false) fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor]
```

Comment: I wish it worked. There is no property of my object I want to rely on, so I seek for the core data saved order to present data as they are ordered in my json (because they are saved in the order they appear in the json).