# How to sort array of objects by Date

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a Core Data item called an expense, which has different properties such as

```
expense.name
expense.amount
```

and also

```
expense.modificationDate
```

I have an array, which is of type expenses, and I want to sort the array. 
I have tried this so far

```
  monthlyExpenses.sort(by: { $0.modificationDate?.compare($1.modificationDate! as Date) == .orderedAscending })
```

but it doesn't seem to work. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Why not sorting the data before the fetch? It has better optimization.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2):

```
monthlyExpense.sorted({ $0.modificationDate> $1.modificationDate})
```

It will sort by ascending and for descending use <.

Comment: just make sure to include a space between `modificationDate` and the operator `>`.

Comment: Tells me that i cant use a binary operator on 2 NSDate operands

Comment: @A.G I think you should use Date() not NSDate

Answer (score 1):

```
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Expenses>(entityName: "Expenses")
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Expenses.date), ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
do {
   expenses = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
} catch {
    print("Cannot fetch Expenses")
}
```

[Answer was here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479412/sort-by-date-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSSortDescriptors` during your fetch. as Example:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "expense")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate", ascending: true)


  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

  return fetchRequest
```